# Coverting JSON to JavaScript Object with just values

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have some JSON where I need to convert just the values to an Object. How would I go about this?

My JSON is

```
[
{
  "WebsiteName": "Acme Inc.",
  "Time": "08:30:00",
  "TheDate": "2021-12-23",
  "Hits": "39"
},
{
  "WebsiteName": "Acme Inc.",
  "Time": "08:45:00",
  "TheDate": "2021-12-23",
  "Hits": "37"
}
]
```

and I am trying to format it like so (without the names)

```
var myObject = [["Acme Inc.", "08:30:00", "2021-12-23", "39"], ["Acme Inc.", "08:45:00", "2021-12-23", "37"]];
```

I need to do this with assuming that the code doesn't know the names.  That way I can reuse the code on another JSON file without having to tweak the code each time.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` to convert the JSON into a JS object, and then you can manipulate the data how you like.

Comment: i think you missed something, your desired output is an array (which is a js-object actually) but seems misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
let json = `[
{
  "WebsiteName": "Acme Inc.",
  "Time": "08:30:00",
  "TheDate": "2021-12-23",
  "Hits": "39"
},
{
  "WebsiteName": "Acme Inc.",
  "Time": "08:45:00",
  "TheDate": "2021-12-23",
  "Hits": "37"
}
]`;

let result = JSON.parse(json).map(e => Object.values(e));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just be aware that `x` isn't JSON.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yep. Forgot about that part. Now it is :)